# android: fix blank scrollview layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

My goal is to show a toolbar at the top of the view, then a TextView, then a ScrollView section and then a footer that always shows at the bottom of the view.  The below only shows the toolbar and the TextView header.  Nothing is showing for the ScrollView section or for the footer at the bottom.  What am I missing here?

```
EditActivity.xml

<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".EditActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" >
    </include>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"  >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/create_skycard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:clickable="false"  />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/myFooter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"  >

        <include layout="@layout/cardview_nobuttons"
            android:id="@+id/cardviewNobuttons"  />

        <include layout="@layout/cardview_previewbuttons"
            android:id="@+id/cardviewPreviewbuttons" />            

    </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>  

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/header"
android:layout_above="@+id/myFooter"
android:fillViewport="true"  >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >      

    <com.wimso.v108.widget.EditText
    ...  />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My guess to another way of doing this: you should create a root RelativeLayout containing a LinearLayout and a RelativeLayout, the linearLayout can hold the toolbar, search bar and the scrollview. While the relative layout should be align ParentBottom = true to hold the footer.

Comment: Ok, making progress.  The ScrollView now shows correctly but the RelativeLayout is not at the bottom of the screen, it is overlayed across the top of the view, over the toolbar.  Any thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should limit height of footer view. I set the `ViewFlipper`'s height to `128dp` for test, so you can calculate your own based on its content.

Second: You should set `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` for the `include` which its id is `toolbar`. To do this you should set height and weight for it as I did.

Third: The height of the `ScrollView` should be `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` to be sure it stretches between header and footer views.

Here is your layout source code after applying the above corrections:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".EditActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/create_skycard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myFooter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.wimso.v108.widget.EditText
            ... />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/cardviewNobuttons"
                layout="@layout/cardview_nobuttons" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/cardviewPreviewbuttons"
                layout="@layout/cardview_previewbuttons" />

        </ViewFlipper>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```